# Powershell Delete files older than X days, but keep at least 1

Tags: powershell

I currently backup my switch/router configs automatically every time we write changes... This is done by through ftp sending a text file to a folder.

I am trying to write a script that would delete all files in a directory older than 15 days. However I want to keep the latest file for each device even if it is older than 15 days.

The format of the file naming is as follows:
Latest File name is Hostname-Config-Change.txt
when it is overwritten by a newer change it gets renamed to:
Hostname-Config-Change_MM-DD-YY_HH-MM-SS_Time.txt

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to delete all files older than 15 days with the date and time in the name. I have no idea how to approach this and although I have found ways to do either of these, I have not found a way to do both.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you could provide.

This is my code so far. I am now to powershell, so any advice would be appreciated.

```
#Set Variables

# Get current date/time then subtract days to keep files.
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)

#Set path of Files to be scanned & deleted
$path = "Directory to Files"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

#End of Script
```

Comment: if you want to keep the newest file ... then you would always keep the one that _does not_ have a date stamp in the name. so you can exclude those an you will always keep the newest file for each host. ///// for the others, you can use `Group-Object` to group by the hostname part of the file, then clobber anything older than 15 days.

Comment: Hello,
How could I actually accomplish that? Would powershell use regex to do that or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Hello, I saw some keywords in what you posted and was able to figure it out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// you can post an Answer to your own Question ... and accept it ... as long as you add the _why_ of it, that is totally legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for easy of use for everyone that might follow. Using the above responses, I was able to figure out how to use regex to just look at any file with a date in the file name that is older than X amount of days. The latest file does not contain a date in the filename so it worked for me. Be warned you will have to adjust the regex depending on the syntax of the date.

```
#Set Variables

# Get current date/time then subtract days to keep files.
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)

#Set path of Files to be scanned & deleted
$path = "D:\BACKUPS\ConfigChange"

# Delete files older than the $limit and matching the dates in the file name.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.BaseName -match '(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})' -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

#End of Script
```